# dont get the right path in laravel for my uploads folder

Tags: laravel, path

i always use this to go to the public folder:

```
src="{{ asset('img/pic.png') }}">
```

everything works perfect

but now is it not possible because i want to show the avatar picture and 
something like this not works

```
<img src="../../public/uploads/avatars/{{$user->avatar}}">
```

so ive used this but it doesnt work i dont know how to go to the uploads folder

does anybody know the reason?

thank you!!!

Comment: Is this the `storage\uploads` folder you are referring to?

Comment: no it is in public\uploads\avatars so the folder exist and the img also but i dont know how to get there

Comment: this is what i get in the explorer: <img src="../../public/uploads/avatars/1536140573.jpg"> but it says : Graphic can not be loaded

Comment: With the `asset()` helper, you have missed out the `uploads/` folder. So this should be `src="{{ asset('uploads/avatars/' . $user->avatar) }}"`

Comment: perfect !! thank you :)

Comment: I've added as an answer, please accept!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the `asset()` helper, you have missed out the uploads/ folder.

So this should be `src="{{ asset('uploads/avatars/' . $user->avatar) }}"`

Answer (score 0):

If your uploads folder is in the public folder, there is no need to use the asset() helper. You could just use the following:

```
<img src="/uploads/avatars/{{$user->avatar}}">
```